# Opening a textfile in MatLab

Tags: matlab, text-files, fopen

I have written a simple textfile using notepad, and I placed the text file in the same folder as a matlab script I want to run. I pretty much want to make a script so that when the user clicks run a  pop-up of my text file will come up purely within matlab.(I will later include separate figures, graphs to pop up at the same time.)
I tried researching, and I found fopen. But when I do fopen('FileName.txt','r');  nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you are looking for, but I guessed that you need to open a file and read its content using Matlab.

```
fid = fopen('FileName.txt','r');  % generate a file identifier
if fid < 0
   error 'Unable to open file ... check file location'
else
   while ~feof(fid)  % while there is a line to read
     disp(fgets(fid))
   end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: A note here is that the file id (`fid`) should always be stored in a variable and that a file which have been opened must be closed again. As long as the file is open no other application may access it.